# Javascript using string input with parseInt and toString

Tags: javascript, python, function, translate

I'm using a psychology software program (called PsychoPy) and I am trying to translate some Python code into javascript. I'm a novice python coder, and have never worked with javascript before.

The python code is as follows:

```
$str(int(expInfo['participant'])%4)+'_block_1.csv'
```

So different participant numbers use data from different .csv files. In Python I'm converting the participant string into an integer first, in order to using modulo on it, and then convert it back into a string to read the full .csv file. I'm trying to translate it into JS using the parseInt so I can use modulo, and then toString to turn it back again.

I have tried something like:  `toString(parseInt(expInfo['participant'])` so far, and it gives an undefined response.

Is it possible to translate that one line of python code to one line of js? Any help would be very very much appreciated, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
`${parseInt(expInfo['participant'])}`
```

In javascript, we call `` this as "template literals", which are string literals allowing embedded expressions. Inside the string literal, we could use ${} to put the value of the instance or variable to the string.

So, by using the code above, you will be able to make the result of parseInt(expInfo['participant']) as string literal.

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to concatenate the string at the end of the python code in js it would be like: `${parseInt(expInfo['participant'])}`.concat("_block_1.csv") or should that just be included in the `` ?

Comment: Update to prior comment – I added everything into the `` and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Go to hear that! No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
`${expInfo['participant']}_block_1.csv`
```